# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form' whilst using SharedModule

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular9, formgroups

I've had this error lots of times and I've always been able to fix it but I think I'm overlooking something this time and I can't get it too work.

As stated in the title, the error I get is `Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.` for the following line of code: `<form [formGroup]="contactSettings">`.

I already checked all stackoverflow posts but they all come down to add the `ReactiveFormsModule` to the module that makes use of ReactiveForms. In my case, which was also in various stackoverflow posts, I should export the `ReactiveFormsModule` in my `SharedModule` and import that `SharedModule` in my `ContactModule` that actually uses the `ReactiveFormsModule`. I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

**contact-settings.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="contactSettings">

</form>
```

**contact-settings.component.ts**

```
export class ContactSettingsComponent extends FormComponent {

  contactSettings: FormGroup = this.fb.group({ //Moving this to constructor or onInit does not fix it
    firstName: ["First name"],
    lastName: ["Last name"],
    emailAdress: ["email", Validators.email],
    gender: ["male"],
    parentCustomerId: ["Parent customer name"],
    language: ["Language"],
    telephone: ["Telephone number"],
    mobilephone: ["Mobile phone number"],
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private contactService: ContactService) {
    super();
  }
}
```

**contact.module.ts**

```
... //imports

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ContactSettingsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ContactRoutingModule,
    SharedMaterialModule, // <--- contains export ReactiveFormsModule and FormsModule
    SharedComponentsModule
  ]
})
export class ContactModule { }
```

**shared-material.module.ts**

```
... //Angular Material imports

//CommonModule
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

//Forms
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

//Browser
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@NgModule({
  //Normally imports are here, but the template I bought does not have this and adding it doesn't fix it either. It worked normally before.
  exports: [
    //CommonModule
    CommonModule,
    //Browser animations
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    //Forms
    ReactiveFormsModule, // <--- clearly present here
    FormsModule,
    //Angular Material Modules
    ...
  ]
})

export class SharedMaterialModule {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My imports were done perfectly. The problem was that my ContactModule was never used in any other module. I had to add load the ContactModule by adding the following code block to my app-routing.module.

```
      {
        path: 'contact',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/contact/contact.module').then(m => m.ContactModule)
      }
```